# In Htpp url openConnection() show error

Tags: android

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { new JsonParse().execute("http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItems.txt");}});}
    public class JsonParse extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try { URI url = new URI(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String linge = "";
                while ((linge = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(linge);}
                return stringBuffer.toString(); } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {if (connection != null){connection.disconnect();try {
 if (reader != null) { reader.close();}} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }}return null }  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result{super.onPostExecute(result);
  tv.setText(result);} }}
```

Comment: format the code and add your logcat out also

Comment: could you post the error from logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's very difficult to read your code but below is an example of how you use `HttpURLConnection`

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4");
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
// Starts the query
conn.connect();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Or there is another approach

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
stream = url.openStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

Now read it using `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`